# Разбиение строки

Tags: python, строки

Как эффективно и красиво организовать функцию, которая будет разбивать строку на лист?
В начале: мне нужно сделать функцию которая будет резать строку на параметры (лист), где элементы разделены пробелом или используются кавычки (в массиве такой элемент может содержать пробелы, но не будет содержать кавычки

```py
>>> def foo(string: str):
...   #...
...   return result

# В кавычках воспринимается ↓ как одно целое
>>> foo('command hello 1 "1 2 3"')
#              ↑ разделитель: пробел
  ["command", "hello", "1", "1 2 3"]
#               Кавычки пропали ↑
```

```py
>>> foo('1 2 3 "1 2 3"')
 ['1', '2', '3', '1 2 3']
>>> foo('# $%^&11')
 ['#', '$%^&11']
>>> foo('1 "1"')
 ['1', '1']
>>> foo('1       3       5')
 ['1', '3', '5']
>>> foo('__ __ __')
 ['__', '__', '__']
>>> foo('       1')
 ['1']
>>> foo('"       1"')
 ['       1']
```

При этом .split() не подходит:

```py
# если я хочу использовать .split
>>> '1 "1 1"'.split()
 ['1', '"1', '1"']
# НО ДОЛЖНО БЫТЬ
>>> foo('1 "1 1"')
 ['1', '1 1']
```

Comment: `shlex.split(string)`

Comment: Оказалось, что такое решение вполне подходит @andreymal

Answer (score 1):

Можно сначала разбить по условию `s.split(' "')` тогда вы сможете разделить строки с кавычками и без, при это закрывающая кавычка останется в строке, по её наличию мы будем понимать как добавлять элемент в результирующий список. Если добавляется строка без кавычек, то `.strip()` удаляет ненужные пробелы

```
def foo(s: str) -> list:
    lst = s.split(' "')  # ['1 2 3', '1 2 3"']
    result = []
    for x in lst:
        if '"' in x:
            result.append(x.replace('"', ''))
        else:
            result += x.strip().split(' ')

    return result


print(foo('1 2 3 "1 2 3"'))   # ['1', '2', '3', '1 2 3']
```

Comment: Ну... Почти. Строка 'a "a" a "a"' будет обработана как ['a', 'a a', 'a'], а не как  ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a']